# Using reg-ex to filter URL's that contain certain words GA

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to filter out all URL's that contain certain words, for example:

I have a URL that looks like this:

www.google.com/&SaveThis=true&SaveType=VeryFast&Page=0

And sometimes the 'Save Type' might change to slow or something. So what I want to do is show all URL's that have the 'SaveType=VeryFast' sometimes this can be in the middle of a very long URL.

I tried this:

```
.*SaveType=VeryFast.*
```

But it didn't work!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Tip #4 on [this page](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034324), it looks like you don't need the `.*` on either end. That is, without the `^` and `$` anchors, using `SaveType=VeryFast` should match any URL that contains those exact characters. It does look like word boundary anchors (`\b`) are not supported, so you will likely also match any URL that contains e.g. `OtherSaveType=VeryFast` or `SaveType=VeryFastly`

Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong with your expression... (?)

Comment: You're right. The `.*` are redundant as the regex is not anchored in any way. If you want to match `SaveType=VeryFast` as a part of a querystring only, then you can use `[?&]SaveType=VeryFast(?:&|$)`. Here's the very same expression explained: http://regex101.com/r/yB3eV9 (if you can use lookarounds, this works too: http://regex101.com/r/sU2jT2)

Comment: Thanks guys, also regex101; brilliant site its been bookmarked!